# Unicode text turns into question marks

Tags: unicode

I am using a program which inserts text on to an image.

http://www.free-picture-editor.com/pixenate/themes/cardmaker/arrowheb.php

When I insert Unicode it turns it into question marks. I did add this line to the top of the php file:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Any idea what else needs to be done to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a program that can handle Unicode characters.

Comment: I am trying to change the code so that it can handle unicode characters. Is it not enough to add this line - <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
 - or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

The image appears fine for me. Unicode characters are what they should be, they are not question marks.  That would imply a data conversion is bein performed to a charset that does not support those characters.  So it has to be an issue with your particular webbrowser.

Something else to check: make sure your webserver is not sending a `Content-Type` header that specifies a different charset that overrides your HTML's  tag.  When I go to that URL, there is no charset specified in the `Content-Type` header, so the HTML charset is used.  But maybe on your machine, your webbrowser is being identified differently and so the webserver sends a charset in the `Content-Type` header.